# Calling R function with se.fit parameter with rpy2 from Python

Tags: python, r, prediction, rpy2

I need to call the R function `predict(fit_hs, type="quantile", se.fit=True, p=0.5)` where predict refers to `survreg` in library survival.

It gives an error about the `se.fit` parameter saying it's a keyword that can't be used.

Could you please help finding a way to call this R function from Python?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can not use "." as part of keywords, replacing "." with "_", so "se_fit", should work.